# Changing the precision using the _controlfp function

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

Having such an implementation of the *main game loop* in the official *Quake 2* source code:

```
while (1)
    {
        // if at a full screen console, don't update unless needed
        if (Minimized || (dedicated && dedicated->value) )
        {
            Sleep (1);
        }

        while (PeekMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE))
        {
            if (!GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
                Com_Quit ();
            sys_msg_time = msg.time;
            TranslateMessage (&msg);
            DispatchMessage (&msg);
        }

        do
        {
            newtime = Sys_Milliseconds ();
            time = newtime - oldtime;
        } while (time < 1);
//          Con_Printf ("time:%5.2f - %5.2f = %5.2f\n", newtime, oldtime, time);

        //  _controlfp( ~( _EM_ZERODIVIDE /*| _EM_INVALID*/ ), _MCW_EM );
        _controlfp( _PC_24, _MCW_PC );
        Qcommon_Frame (time);

        oldtime = newtime;
    }
```

My question is about the

```
_controlfp( _PC_24, _MCW_PC );
```

line.

What do really calling the `_controlfp` function do and what's its purpose here?

P.S.

Can somebody please be so nice and give me just a simple c++ example illustrating the usage of changing the repression control using `_controlfp` function?

Comment: _"...sets the floating-point control word. The floating-point control word enables the program to change the precision, rounding, and infinity modes, depending on the platform...."_ - documented here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/control87-controlfp-control87-2?view=msvc-160 What parts of the doc do you not understand ?

Comment: @ As I've written  I'm interested in `Precision control` aspect. Can You be so nice and show me a simple c++ code showing the results of changing the Precision using this function?

Comment: That's what the posted code does - `_PC_24` set the precision to 24 bits.

Comment: @RichardCritten Ok, but can You please supply me a code that illustrates it on an example (some simple calculations, etc)?